# What is meant by using the term "B'nei Brit" in "U'Chtov Lechayim"?

Tags: words, shemoneh-esrei, aseres-yemei-teshuva

During the Ten Days of Repentance, we add a phrase in the 2nd to last blessing of *Amidah*:

> וכתוב לחיים טובים כל בני בריתיך
>
> "May all the children of your covenant be inscribed for good life."

Why is the term בני בריתיך used here as opposed to just simplifying it to כתבינו לחיים טובים ? (Yes, I'm aware that this would repeat what was said in the 1st blessing almost verbatim, but, we're already repeating the request to be inscribed for good life in all 4 of the insertions, anyway.)

I know what the term means, but, I am curious as to what additional idea is being conveyed, here, and, specifically, how that idea relates to this particular *bracha*. The term is not used in any of the other 3 places.

Comment: Needs some research!